# Libraries in script interfere with Rmd when calling render directly

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Suppose I have the following `Rmd` file called `render-issues.Rmd`:

````
---
title: "Render Issues"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r lib}
library(dplyr)
```

```{r clash}
mtcars %>% summarize(n = n())
```
````

When pressing the `knit` button in R-Studio everything works as expected.

If I try to render this document "by hand" i.e. by calling `rmarkdown::render` in a script, I may fail:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rmarkdown)
library(Hmisc) ## note the conflict of summarize

render("render_issues.Rmd")
```

This won't render because `summarize` now refers to `Hmisc::summarize`.

Thus, I thought I could provide `envir` to make sure my `Rmd` file is not disturbed by the libs in my render script

```
### Use `parent` to simulate a fresh R session with the 
### standard libs loaded
render("render_issues.Rmd", 
       envir = new.env(parent = as.environment("package:stats")))
```

However, this won't work either, because now `dplyr` is not (re-) loaded and thus functions cannot be found. Apparently, `library` checks the whole search path irrespective of my environment choice.

So what is the canonical way of rendering a report from a script? Overall I want the render process to be completely un-disturbed by the calling script. Is the only solution to spawn a new R session as highlighted [in this article](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/rmarkdown-render.html#rmarkdown-render)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the canonical way is to spawn a new R session.

You could alternatively play whack-a-mole and fix up the conflicts one at a time, by putting

```
summarize <- dplyr::summarize
```

and similar fixups in the individual Rmd files (or in the script), but I'd recommend running in a clean session.  The method listed in the bookdown chapter isn't the only way, you can use base R functions to do it, e.g.

```
system("Rscript -e \"rmarkdown::render('render_issues.Rmd')\"")
```

(which I'd probably put in a function if you're calling it more than once).

Comment: Thanks for confirming my assumptions. Is there a way how we could trick `library` to load packages unconditionally of whether they were loaded already? Because in this case my `envir` would also work?

Comment: There are probably hacks that would do that, but there's no legal way.  They would almost certainly cause other problems, e.g. having two method tables for the same generic, etc.